# How to improve massive UPDATE from SELECT performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want update a table with data from another table. My current approach looks like this:

```
UPDATE items t1
SET (name, manufacturer_id, price) =
    (SELECT
        t2.item_name,
        t2.item_manufacturer_id,
        t2.item_price
    FROM staged_items t2
    WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
      AND t2.operation = 'modification'
      AND t1.id = t2.item_id)
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM staged_items t2
WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
  AND t2.operation = 'modification'
  AND t1.id = t2.item_id)
```

The problem is that it's taking too long and I don't know how to get feedback or an estimation about how long will it take. I have been waiting for about 3 hours without results and there are not pending operations on `v$session_longops`.

I would like to know **how to improve the performance of the update** or maybe **another approach that is more efficient**. Also, I'd like to know **how to check the status of the running query**.

#### Some remarks

- The `staged_items` tables is expected to contain at least **300 million** entries and grow to billions of entries in the long run.

  - Only "few entries" (from 0 to ~1 million) are expected to match the conditions (`t2.upgrade_version = somenumber` and `t2.operation = 'modification'`) every time I run the `UPDATE`.
  - Currently I'm testing with a `staged_items`tables of 1 million entries, all of them matching the conditions.
- The `items` table is expected to have about **20 million** entries and stay in that order of magnitude in the long run.

  - Currently I'm testing with about ~1 million entries, most of them matched by the `UPDATE`.
- Currently I have no indexes but I'm thinking of creating them on `items.id`, `staged_items.item_id`, `staged_items.upgrade_version` and `staged_items.operation`

  - I'm not quite sure of which indexes would be really needed and useful
- The `UPDATE`is not expected to modify any indexed column, anyway this could change in the future so I'd appreaciate comments about how that scenario would have an impact on the proposed solution.

**Edit:** Finally, instead of checking the status of the running query, I opted for paginating the query into multiple queries using rownum. This allows me to wait for every (smaller) query and check and approximate percentage of completeness.

Considering that, my original query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE items t1
SET (name, manufacturer_id, price) =
    (
      SELECT
        t2.item_name,
        t2.item_manufacturer_id,
        t2.item_price
      FROM
        (
          SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
            a.*,
            ROWNUM rnum
          FROM
            (
              SELECT *          
              FROM staged_items t2
              WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
                AND t2.operation = 'modification'
                AND t1.id = t2.item_id
              ORDER BY t2.id
            ) a
          WHERE ROWNUM <= MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH
        )
      WHERE rnum >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH
    )
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM staged_items t2
WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
  AND t2.operation = 'modification'
  AND t1.id = t2.item_id)
```

(Based on the **Pagination with ROWNUM** section of [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html))

Anyway, for the outer `WHERE`, I used [Gordon Linoff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519956/how-to-improve-massive-update-from-select-performance/39520173#39520173).

Comment: how often do you need to run the updates? (one time only/daily/weekly/quarterly/yearly ...)

Comment: @tbone: normally weekly or at most twice a week. Anyway, the tables should preferrably not be locked while updating since the system should not have long downtimes.

Comment: If it took 24 hours it would be acceptable, anyway my concern is that I currently don't know how to estimate the amount of time that it will take. What if my current approach takes years to finish?

Comment: I think that's what `MERGE` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, you want an index on:

```
staged_items(item_id, upgrade_version, operation)
```

I am also thinking that you could rewrite the outer `where` clause as:

```
WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT t2.item_id
                FROM staged_items t2
                WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234 AND t2.operation = 'modification'
               )
```

Then, you want indexes on `staged_items(upgrade_version, operation, item_id)` and `items(id)`.  Note that the order of the keys in the index is important and you still want the first index for the correlated subquery to get the values.

Comment: how about index as proposed and MERGE statement to update?

Comment: @Aishu . . . That should also be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you propose that order for the first index, since inside my `WHERE` I first check `t2.upgrade_version`, then `t2.operation` and finally `t2.item_id`. Why not use the `staged_items(upgrade_version, operation, item_id)` order for the original query? Could you elaborate more on that, please?

Comment: Also, I think you wanted to say `item_id` instead of `id` in the first index you suggest.

Comment: Ok, maybe my question was silly, since the order of the conditions inside a where clause doesn't matter. What I'd like to understand is what's the idea behind the two different indexes you suggest. What improvement do you expect with you version of the outer where?

Comment: @Sam . . . Yes, it is `item_id`.  You need that to "get into" the correlated subquery as quickly as possible.  The other two columns are used for quick reference so the data pages don't have to be loaded to complete the condition.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a situation that you need to do massive DML operations in a table, you can use BULK COLLECT and FORALL.  To get a state of the operation, I usually create a log table to store the information. 
And, on top of that, you could add some indexes to speed up the queries.

I would not use a MERGE statement because it is really slow.

So, a possible solution for you would be something like this:

```
create table log_load(table_name varchar2(50), create_date date, message varchar2(500));

declare
cursor cur_upd is
SELECT rowid as row_id
FROM items t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM staged_items t2
  WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
  AND t2.operation = 'modification'
  AND t1.id = t2.item_id);

TYPE fetch_array IS TABLE OF cur_upd%ROWTYPE;
s_array fetch_array;
BEGIN
    insert into log_load values ('item',sysdate,'Start')
    commit;

    OPEN cur_upd;
    upd_ := 0;
    LOOP
         FETCH cur_upd BULK COLLECT INTO s_array LIMIT 50000;
         upd_ := upd_ + s_array.COUNT;

        FORALL i IN 1..s_array.COUNT
         UPDATE items t1
         SET (name, manufacturer_id, price) =
          (SELECT t2.item_name, t2.item_manufacturer_id, t2.item_price
           FROM staged_items t2
           WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
           AND t2.operation = 'modification'
           AND t1.id = t2.item_id)
         WHERE t1.rowid = cur_upd[i].row_id;

    insert into log_load values ('item',sysdate,'50000 updated.')
    commit;

    EXIT WHEN cur_upd%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur_upd;
   insert into log_load values ('item',sysdate,'end');
   commit;

END;
```

Comment: `cur_upd[i].row_id` is not valid Oracle syntax. Also when you use `ROWID` you should always define your cursor with `FOR UPDATE` clause to ensure that the records are locked.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old joke about a man who walks into a doctors office.  He waves his arm around in a circle and says "Doc, it hurts when I do this!".  The Doctor looks at him and says  "Well, then don't do that!"

I think your main issue is that your staging table is huge, but you really only need to look at a small fraction of that data.  Don't update using the full staging table.  Perhaps you can try creating a materialized view that you refresh complete just before running your updates.  Your mat view would be based on:

```
SELECT
        t2.item_name,
        t2.item_manufacturer_id,
        t2.item_price
    FROM staged_items t2
    WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
      AND t2.operation = 'modification'
```

You could add parallel hints to this also.  If you need to change these values each time your run the updates, you can alternatively create a regular table via a CTAS (create table as select), using the same SQL but with different values (upgrade_version = 5678 or whatever).

Your other issue is with tracking.  The cleanest way to do it is in pl/sql.  It may not be as simple as a single update statement, but you get the ability to add logging, and control your commit points (your DBAs will be thankful of this).

Your driving table will be the mat view (or CTAS table).  Something like:

```
declare
  cursor sel_stage_mv is
  select * from my_stage_mv;

  l_cnt pls_integer := 0;
  l_upd_cnt pls_integer := 0;
begin
  for rec in sel_stage_mv
  loop
    l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;

    -- all needed indexes are on main table (id, etc...)
    update main_table
    set ...
    where id = rec.id;

    l_upd_cnt := l_upd_cnt + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    if (mod(l_cnt, 10000) = 0) then
      -- insert to some log table via autonomous procedure
      ins_log(...l_upd_cnt ...);
      commit;
    end if;

  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

Run all this off hours of course.  I'm also making some assumptions about your environment and transactional requirements, but only you know what will work for your setup and needs.

Comment: I doubt that a **row-by-row** updates would be faster than a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think running a single update thats pulling from hundreds of millions of rows, and not knowing where you are in the process, is a much bigger issue.  And if the initial mat view (or even a regular table via CTAS) is used as I describe, you'd be surprised.

Comment: +1 for suggesting CTAS. Anyway, I'm not quite sure that is my problem since in my test case most of the rows of `staged_items` match the query and the update is slow anyway. Also, instead of a row by row approach, I'm thinking of batching the updates using rownum multiple times, every time with a fixed number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one:

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT t1.name, t1.manufacturer_id, t1.price,
   t2.item_name,
   t2.item_manufacturer_id,
   t2.item_price, 
   t1.id, t2.item_id
from items t1
   JOIN staged_items t2 on t1.id = t2.item_id
WHERE t2.upgrade_version = 1234
   AND t2.operation = 'modification')
SET name = item_name, 
   manufacturer_id = item_manufacturer_id, 
   price = item_price;
```

It should avoid the double SELECT of staged_items and thus can be faster.
However, I did not test it.